# Getting supported color effects and using them

Tags: android, android-camera, effects

In my app I want to use collor effects on camera. I'm getting a list of them by using `getSupportedColorEffects()` function, however it gives me just names of them. Is there any easy way to simply use them ? I mean, what I'm getting is for example "incandescent", but to use it i have to use: `camera_parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_INCANDESCENT)`, so is there any onther way than manually assigning each word to each parameter ? And what if list of effects may differ on different devices?
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the camera hardware. You can try this to find supported colour effects:

```
params = camera.getParameters();
List<String> list=params.getSupportedColorEffects();
camera.setParameters(params);

params = camera.getParameters();
params.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_NONE);
camera.setParameters(params);
```

Comment: You don't understand what I want to do, I know how to get supported color effects and how to set a collor effect, but for example i'm showing to user a box with multiple color effects names for example: aqua, sepia, negative (these are the names from list which I got) and he selects sepia, and now how to set sepia effect easily, how to connect word "sepia" with "Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_SEPIA" cause you can't do something like: "params.setColorEffect(sepia)"

Answer (score 0):

The setter methods take string arguments.  So you simply use the raw string of the effect you want to use.  This goes for most setters in the params.  Of course you cannot put any string you want in there, it must be from the support list.

```
Set<String> effects = params.getSupportedColorEffects();
String effect = chooseEffect(effects);
params.setColorEffect(effect);
camera.setParameters(params);
```